# Cache results of Swift hash(into:) Hashable protocol requirement

Tags: swift, hash, hashable

I have a class being heavily used in Sets and Dictionaries.
For performance reasons this class implements `Hashable` in a old way and caches the computed hash:

```
let hashValue: Int

init(...) {
    self.hashValue = ...
}
```

In Xcode 10.2 I see a warning, that `hashValue` is deprected and will stop being a protocol requirement soon.

What bothers me is a lack of ability to cache the computed hash anyhow, because `hash(into:)` does not return anything.

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(...)
}
```

Consider the following example in a playground

```
class Class: Hashable {
    let param: Int

    init(param: Int) {
        self.param = param
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Class, rhs: Class) -> Bool {
        return lhs.param == rhs.param
    }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        print("in hash")
        hasher.combine(param)
    }
}

var dict = [Class: Int]()
let instance = Class(param: 1)
dict[instance] = 1
dict[instance] = 2
```

You will see the following logs

```
in hash
in hash
in hash
```

I have no idea, why we see 3 calls instead of 2, but we do =).

So, every time you use a same instance as a dictionary key or add this instance into a set, you get a new `hash(into:)` call.

In my code such an overhead turned out to be very expensive. Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 6):

One option is to create your own `Hasher`, feed it the "essential components" of your instance and then call [`finalize()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hasher/2995580-finalize) in order to get out an `Int` hash value, which can be cached.

For example:

```
class C : Hashable {
  let param: Int

  private lazy var cachedHashValue: Int = {
    var hasher = Hasher()
    hasher.combine(param)
    // ... repeat for other "essential components"
    return hasher.finalize()
  }()

  init(param: Int) {
    self.param = param
  }

  static func ==(lhs: C, rhs: C) -> Bool {
    return lhs.param == rhs.param
  }

  public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(cachedHashValue)
  }
}
```

A couple of things to note about this:

- It relies on your "essential components" being immutable, otherwise a new hash value would need calculating upon mutation.
- Hash values aren't guaranteed to remain stable across executions of the program, so don't serialise `cachedHashValue`.

Obviously in the case of storing a single `Int` this won't be all that effective, but for more expensive instances this could well help improve performance.

Comment: Looks like a hack =))

Comment: I will measure it and share a report a bit later =)

Comment: I wouldn't really call it a hack given this is how `Hasher` is supposed to be used. I'll admit it's a bit more convoluted than how you would have done it with `hashValue`, but, as Martin says, the new API allows for much more robust hash values.